# Chromecast new Cast.Api()

Tags: chromecast

I just started using Chromecast SDK today and got bit confused with its APIs and samples given in the web.

What I am trying to do is to send some messages to the Chromecast so it will display them on the big screen. I am going to use Chrome API with HTML5/JS/CSS.

Most examples (https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world/blob/master/sender/index.html , http://nerdwin15.com/2013/10/chromecast-development-part-one-chrome-sender/) in the web uses new Cast.Api() in the sender and uses an Activity in doing so. But I could not find a reference to a Cast.Api in the Chrome API. Most Google references deal with Media and I am not sure whether I have to use them. So to sum up, following are the questions I have (Sorry! I did read the API and developer guide but I am still clueless).

1. Do I have to write a custom receiver to show text on TV screen. Can't I survive default receiver, chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID
2. Is handling multimedia files different from displaying text on the Chromecast or can I set the mime type to text/html and send a text stream (doesn't work for me at the moment)
3. Are those examples on the web uses a deprecated way of sending data to chromecast?

Thanks in advance,
Ish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer from following documents,

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps

https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/blob/master/chromehellotext.html

Will try them and let you all know!

Following example page is very useful for anyone who try writing chromecast apps

https://github.com/googlecast

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you fared, but here are some quick responses to your questions.

1. Yes, you have to write a custom receiver if you want to do anything other than sending images, audio, or video to the Chromecast. You can see a list of supported media Default Media Receiver here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media
2. Yes (see above), it requires a custom receiver, which will also require your own appId and I'm pretty sure a custom namespace.
3. To my knowledge, all of the examples up on https://github.com/googlecast should be relevant, but I am working on a few wrappers to try to simplify getting up and running with custom Chrome Sender and Receiver apps. You can check them out here: https://github.com/googlecast Let me know if those help, and if you have any feedback to share.

I hope you've already figured all this stuff out, but if not hopefully this is useful.